# How to Groupby based on multiple field and display all columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, pandas-groupby, data-analysis

I am trying to create a csv file where if few columns are same then i will merge row with similar value into one row .

eg:

Input :

```
Party_No install_date  Start_date  End_date  Product_family  Version City state 
 111     24-05-2018    25-05-2019 21-03-2020  storage           1     LA   USA
 111     24-05-2018    25-05-2019 21-03-2020  storage           1     KA   USA
 111     24-05-2018    25-05-2019 21-03-2020   storage          2     PA   UK
```

Output

```
Party_No install_date  Start_date  End_date  Product_family Version City   state 
111     24-05-2018    25-05-2019 21-03-2020  storage         1,2 LA,KA,PA UK,USA
```

ex : in my case

if value of party_number , item_install_date ,Contract_subline_date , Contract_Subline_end_date , Instance_family

i will merger row with same value into one row . other column apart from above mentioned will have comma separated value

Input CSV file [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UeKbUdg2cvhTM_hLexX2IbkYrguYPpNH)

Expected output CSV [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1P48J2tRGRxA495syu2VpRi0Ca3BUF3em)

Code i tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import np

  df = None
  df = pd.read_csv("Export.csv")
  df.fillna(0,inplace=True)



pf=df.groupby(['PARTY_NUMBER','ITEM_INSTALL_DATE','CONTRACT_SUBLINE_START_DATE','CONTRACT_SUBLINE_END_DATE','INSTANCE_PRODUCT_FAMILY']).agg([','.join])

pf.to_csv("result1.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `unqiue` (or `set` when order is not important)

```
df.groupby(['...']).agg(lambda x : ','.join(x.unique())) # set(x)
```

Comment: I Tried i am getting   " AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'unique' "

Comment: columns which are specified in groupby is not getting printed in the final output

Comment: @RITESHSANJAYMAHAJAN how about try `df.groupby(['...']).agg(lambda x : ','.join(set(x)))`

Comment: Set has solved the duplicate value problem . but still not able to see the columns which are mention in groupby . i am getting only version ,city,state columns .. other columns such as party_number , install_date , startdate ,End date ,product family are not coming in the final output ... only the column version ,city  and  state are getting displayed

Comment: @RITESHSANJAYMAHAJAN `df.groupby(['...']).agg(lambda x : ','.join(set(x))).reset_index()`